# Why is my dart2js JS file larger with static injector code generator and smaller with dynamic? (angular.dart)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

So I finally got the static injector/parser code generator working (realizing I had to add some of my own things). First, I don't know where I'm supposed to see a longer process (as the readme on github was explaining)...But either way, I noticed that the main.dart.js file generated by dart2js is actually larger (by about 100kb) compared to the dynamic generator.

I know it was suggested not to use the initilizer-dev.dart in production and instead use this static injector/parser that initializer-prod.dart uses...But why? Is there some sort of performance benefit at the cost of that increased file size?

I already worry about the dart2js JS files being so large to begin with, so I'm leaning toward preferring this smaller file size. Unless that's a huge mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the performance gain is by using less reflection. I can imagine that creating explicit code for the actions otherwise done by generic code use some space but I also wonder that the difference is quite notable.

Comment: What Günter said. And if you find performance of dynamic injector/parser sufficient then feel to use them in production.